# How to pass fixture values to a parametrize'd pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

How to pass fixture values to a parametrize'd pytest? What I want to do is:

```
@pytest.fixture
def value():
    return "some value"

@pytest.mark.parametrize("bar", [value])
def test_foo(bar):
    assert isinstance(bar, str) # fails, bar is type `function`
    assert isinstance(bar(), str) # fails that "bar()" should not be called directly
```

Comment: Are you sure about that breakpoint? Nothing in this code example will call `value()`.  The line with `bar()` would have called it, if not for the assertion above firing.

Comment: @wim you're right; I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Is there a good reason that `value` has to be a fixture?  There are ways to make this work, but if value can be a regular function instead it's much easier (you just call the function)

Comment: @wim I am new to this stuff, and my understanding is that fixture is the preferred way to inject test data. Right, I could alternatively create a function, or global variable, but was trying to get it to work with fixture.  And of course this is an overly simplified example of what I'm trying to do, but it illustrates the point.

Comment: The parametrization happens at the test collection phase so fixtures haven't been entered yet. Fixtures are not the preferred way to pass test data, they're really more for controlling setup/teardown context around a test. If you don't need the test data to come from a fixture then don't overcomplicate it ..

Comment: Thanks. What would be the preferred/Pythonic/Pytest way then?

Answer (score 1):

I think what @wim is saying can be illustrated by this example that turns `value()` into a simple function that can be used to generate test data used in several tests through `@pytest.mark.parametrize`.

```py
import pytest

def value():
    """Generate test values"""
    values = ["some value", lambda x: x]
    for value in values:
        yield value


@pytest.mark.parametrize("bar", value())
def test_function(bar):
    """Test if the value is a function"""
    assert callable(bar), f"{bar} is not a function"


@pytest.mark.parametrize("bar", value())
def test_string(bar):
    """Test if the value is a string"""
    assert isinstance(bar, str), f"{bar} is not a string"
```

The output is.

```sh
pytest -rA fixture_param.py
# PASSED fixture_param.py::test_function[<lambda>]
# PASSED fixture_param.py::test_string[some value]
# FAILED fixture_param.py::test_function[some value] - AssertionError: some value is not a function
# FAILED fixture_param.py::test_string[<lambda>] - AssertionError: <function value.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fd1b301b320> is not a string
```